# Text rotation Flex

Tags: apache-flex, text, rotation, angle

How to rotate text (s:label)? I've tried using rotationZ but instead of rotating text it rotates each letter with some weird effect... How to change text angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if effects:

http://www.eonflex.com/flex/4.1/langref/spark/effects/Rotate.html#includeExamplesSummary

if properties:
http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/Label.html#propertySummary look for rotation

and for samples:

http://flex.gormagon.org/2007/04/12/text-rotation/

http://creative-geeks.com/blog/2009/05/26/rotate-text-using-embedded-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

`<s:Label rotation="270" text="Your Text"/>` reads down to up

`<s:Label rotation="90" text="Your Text"/>` reads up to down

If you want to align it vertically, wrap it in a VGroup with spacers:

```
<s:VGroup height="100%">
    <s:Spacer height="50%" />
    <s:Label rotation="270" text="Your Text"/>
    <s:Spacer height="50%" />
</s:VGroup>
```